# Repeating characters in ubuntu 20.04 boot

Tags: character, repeat, startup, boot, ubuntu-20.04

There are some repeating characters when my ubuntu 20.04 is booting, like [[^~`[[^~[[^~ ...` it seems like someone is pushing specific buttons but pushing buttons doesn't write anything when I try. Also sometimes when I'm writing something my keyboard starts repeating 0, and it stops when I push another button. I think it may be related to that problem. Is that a software bug or a hardware problem? What should I do? I add a picture of that. My laptop model is `Lenovo Ideapad 520`. (about three months ago I spilt a cup of tea on my laptop but these problems appeared recently, I'm not sure if they are related)

[Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06jUU.jpg)

Comment: (Your special person may be not amused at the notion of you pushing unspecific bottoms. And don't try and tell them you just *tried*.)

Answer (score -1):

this is most likely a direct issue of you adding tea to your keyboard.
I have previously worked with repairing computers and sometimes a customer could tell you they dropped a glass of water in their keyboard a year ago and one day the computer couldn't turn on or their keyboard didn't work correctly.

without going into an over technical explanation, this is something that happens, and when you spill water in your computer (or any other type of liquid) the connectors and fuses in the board might get damaged and it can take a while before the problems start showing.

you can do 2 things, if possible you can deactivate the keyboard on your laptop and buy a USB keyboard and use that, which might work forever or to some other water related problem occurs.

The best solution is to bring your laptop to a computer repair service and tell them what happened, they'll be able to pull it apart and look for damage and might be able to just clean it with isopropyl and save it that way, or they will be able to tell you what to do.

Really depends on your budget and the age of the laptop tbh as depending where you live the repair can be costly.

Comment: @realmarv you are welcome, if this was what you were looking for could you mark it as the answer for future visitors ?